# Transferring a list to another class throws Inconsistent accessibility error

Tags: c#, list

So I have created a List of a Custom Class called `FinalPixel`, and I want to transfer the list from one form to another, so I have put `List<FinalPixel>` in the constructor for my second from like so:

```
public FinalForm(List<FinalPixel> FinalPixels)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.FinalPixels = FinalPixels;
}
```

And then I create the second form with:

```
FinalForm fF = new FinalForm(FinalPixels);
fF.ShowDialog();
```

However it throws this build-time error:

> Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' is less accessible than method 'Pie_X.FinalForm.FinalForm(System.Collections.Generic.List)'    D:\Users\Arch\Games\C# Games\Pie X\Pie X\FinalForm.cs

Comment: Make `FinalPixel` a `public` class instead of `internal`. Alternately, make the `FinalForm` constructor `internal` instead of `public`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Pie_X.FinalPixel` is not public.

Make `Pie_X.FinalPixel` `public` or make `public FinalForm(List<FinalPixel> FinalPixels)` `internal`.